# webpack HMR (Hot-Module Replacement) in nestjs error: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: webpack, nestjs, nestjs-config

I cloned this project from Github: https://github.com/brocoders/nestjs-boilerplate

Then I set up webpack HMR (Hot-Module Replacement) according to instructions from nestjs documentation: https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/hot-reload

Then I ran the command `nest build --webpack --webpackPath webpack-hmr.config.js --watch` and got the error as shown in the image: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

[image]

I have tried searching and trying every tutorial on google but it doesn't work, please help me.